# Can I use 2 primary key id in the hibernate mapping file?

Tags: hibernate

`

```
<hibernate-mapping>

<class name="beans.EmployeeBean" table="employeedetails" schema="Employee">
<id name="empId" column="empid"/>
<id name="employeeusername" column="username"/>
<property name="firstname" column="firstname"/>
<property name="designation" column="designation"/>
<property name="email" column="email"/>
<property name="role" column="role"/>
</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

In this code when i am putting the second id username i am getting error and in my database also in 1 table i put 2 columns as primary key.

Comment: Did you try the answer suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642101/how-do-i-create-a-composite-primary-key-in-hibernate-within-the-hbm-xml-file

Answer (score 1):

You can't, but you can make a property unique:

```
<property name="employeeusername" column="username" not-null="true" unique="true"/>
```